# Curly Bracket Problems

Tags: c#, unityscript

I am currently working on my code however I have run into a snag after //Off screen to the RIGHT instead of the curly bracket closing off my if statement it closes off the whole code. Can anyone tell me why? The curly brackets before this part work fine. 
Below is my code:

```
public class ShipPlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

//The reference to the bullet prefab. To be populated in the editor via the Inspector window.
public Projectile Bullet;

//Determines the screen bounds in relation to the player object. This camera object needs to e populated this attribute in the Inspector
public Camera CameraObject;

//Control how quickly we can fire (delay between shots)
public float FireRate = 0.5f;

//The amount of time since we last fired our weapon
private float FireTimer = 0.0f;

//Used to control how fast the ship moves
[Range(1f, 100f)]
[SerializeField]
public float MoveSpeed = 25.0f;

//Used to control how fast the ship moves when the t button is pressed
[Range(1f, 100f)]
[SerializeField]
public float ThrusterSpeed = 50.0f;

//Helper vector for updating the ship's position declared here since it is used every update/tick and we do not want to waste CPU power recreating it constantly.
private Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;

public Rigidbody rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {

    UpdatePosition();
    UpdateFiring();
    FixedUpdate();

}

//Update the position of the ship based on the "Horizontal" and "Vertical" input
void UpdatePosition() {
    //Move the player laterally in the 'X' coordinate
    movement.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed;

    //Move the player laterally in the 'Y' coordinate
    movement.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed;

    //Apply the movement vector to the game object's postion
    gameObject.transform.Translate(movement);

    //Transform the 3D world position to a screen pixel location
    Vector3 screenPosition = CameraObject.WorldToScreenPoint(
                                gameObject.transform.position);
}

    //Off screen to the RIGHT
    if (screenPosition.x > Screen.width) {

        //Clamp (reset) to the screen's right side
        screenPosition.x = 0; 

        //Transform clamped screen position to the world space and assign to player ship
        gameObject.transform.position = CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); }

    //Off screen to the LEFT
    else if (screenPosition.x< 0) 

        //Clamp (reset) to the screen's left side
        screenPosition.x = Screen.width;

        //Transform clamped screen position to world space and assign player to ship
        gameObject.transform.position = CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); 

    //Off screen to the TOP
    if (screenPosition.y > Screen.width) 
        //Clamp (reset) to the screen's top side
        screenPosition.y = 0;

        //Transform clamped screen position ti the world space and assign to the player ship
        gameObject.transform.position =
            CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); }

    //Off screen to the BOTTOM
    else if (screenPosition.y< 0) {

        //Clamp (reset) to the screen's bottom side
        screenPosition.y = 0;

        //Transform clamped screen position to the world space and assign player to the ship
        gameObject.transform.position =
            CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); 

    void FixedUpdate()
     if (Input.GetKey.(KeyCode.T)) {

     rb.AddForce(0, 0, ThrusterSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse); }


//Update the firing of the ship based on "Fire1" inout
void UpdateFiring() {

//Accumulate time each frame, when the fire key is pressed, we check if enough time has passed.
FireTimer += Time.deltaTime;

//Detect if the fire button has been pressed.
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) { }

    //Has the fire timer exceeded the amount o time between the spawning of projectiles?
    if (FireTimer > FireRate) { }

        //Reset the timer so it will start counting from scratch for the next shot.
        FireTimer = 0;

//Call the function which handles the spawning of projectiles.
DoWeaponFire(); }

//Handles the spawning of the projectile
void DoWeaponFire() {

//Create a new instance of the bullet and place it at the location of the player, facing in the same direction.
Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation); }
```

}

Comment: This is where having proper cleanly formatted code would help you .. please try to understand how to fix what it is your have written.. this is C# not javascript style coding..

Answer (score 4):

I did not fully understand your code but by observing the pattern, I suspect you may miss a few bracket at the position I have commented.

```js
    if (screenPosition.x > Screen.width) {

        screenPosition.x = 0; 

        gameObject.transform.position = CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); }

    else if (screenPosition.x< 0) // <--- need { ?

     
        screenPosition.x = Screen.width;

       
        gameObject.transform.position = CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); 
    // <--- need } ?
   
    if (screenPosition.y > Screen.width) // <--- need { ?
        screenPosition.y = 0;
        gameObject.transform.position =
            CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); }

    else if (screenPosition.y< 0) {

      
        screenPosition.y = 0;
        gameObject.transform.position =
            CameraObject.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); 
      // <-- need }?
```